# insert data with ajax in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

i am trying to insert data to a database table using ajax in yii2. but i don't really know how to go about it i want to send the post data to the controller the problem seems to come from the ajax script .it is meant to show me the value of rate which is 'up'. instead the alert show me.

this is my view class

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use app\models\MyProfile;
use app\models\LikeDiscussion;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\Topic;
use common\models\Thumbs;
use common\models\Comment;
use common\models\Candidate;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
<button  id="save" name="save" class="readmore">up</button>
```

this is my js file.

```
var fac= document.getElementById("save");
    fac.onclick = function fun(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/index.php?r=site%2Fblog',
            type: 'post',
            data:{"rate": 'up'},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
```

this is my contoller class

```
<?php 

    public function actionBlog(){
        $thumbs= new Thumbs(); 
        if(isset($_POST['rate'])){
            $thumbs->user=Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
            $thumbs->topic_id = 1;
            $thumbs->rate = $_POST['rate'];
            $thumbs->load($_POST);
            $thumbs->save();
        }

        return $this->render('blog');
    }
```

this is what i get as the alert

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 

    public function actionBlog(){
        $thumbs= new Thumbs(); 
        if(isset($_POST['rate'])){
            $thumbs->user=Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
            $thumbs->topic_id = 1;
            $thumbs->rate = $_POST['rate'];
            $thumbs->load($_POST);
            $thumbs->save();

            if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
                return $thumbs->rate;
        }

        return $this->render('blog');
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `runtime/logs/app.log` And screen Network tab from Chrome console?

Comment: do you know any other way , i just want to add thumbs up and thumbs down .and i want to use ajax because i not want the buttons to be in a form